# Linking rows in different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried searching for a solution for this problem but I am unsure how to formulate the question and the answers that I have found isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

I have 2 tables in my db:

#### Artist

```
name -  artistid(a_i)
Abba - 1
```

#### Songlist

```
songid - songid2(a_i) - songtext - songname - artistname
1        -    1  -  This is the song text - mamma mia - abba
1   - 2 - This is the song text - song2 - abba
```

---

- Songid = same as artistid (this works like an album)
- songid2 = different songs from this specific artist.

When I choose an artist, I get to choose from a list of different songs. The problem is when I want to get the songtext/songname for "`songid2`".

This is how it looks

- Choose artist > getArtistSongs.php?artistid=1
- Choose song > show.php?songid2=1

Now in this case the text will show up because songid2=artistid
But if I choose song: `songid2=2`, obviously nothing will show up. Now my question is, how can I query this out correctly in php?

EDIt: I managed to get the correct data for the song text thanks to OIbisidian, but now I have trouble echoing out the songs for the artist..  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but either all songs on the database show up, and they aren't clickable because "`songid2`" wont assign to them.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT songname, songid2 * From bridge b, songs s, artists a WHERE s.songid2 = a.artistid");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "</br>";
        echo "<div id='artistlista'>";
        echo "<ul><li><a href='show.php?songid2=" . $row['songid2'] . "'>" . $row['songname'] .  "</a></li></ul>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

Comment: Post some data from your database along with your question..It's a bit confusing now..!

Comment: Are you sure that you are running the correct query and you have records available in your table regarding what you are trying to get from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> songid2 = different songs from this specific artist.

The problem doesn't sound to be with PHP at all; the problem sounds to be with the way you are storing your data in your tables. You shouldn't have multiple values associated to one variable! It sounds like you would benefit from two tables to store songs and artists respectively, plus a **[bridging table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)**.

A bridging table (also known as an associative entity) allows you to have two foreign keys that are primary keys in another table, solving the problem of a many-to-many relationship.

A more logical approach would be a table similar to the following:

Table 1 - **Songs**:

```
   ID   | Song Name
-------------------
   1    | Hello
   2    | Goodbye
```

Table 2 - **Artists**:

```
   ID    | Arist Name
---------------------
   1     | ABBA
   2     | ABC
```

Bridging Table (associates songs to artists):

```
   ID    | Song ID   | Artist ID
--------------------------------
   1     | 2         | 1
   2     | 1         | 2
   3     | 2         | 2
```

In the above example, both `ABBA` and `ABC` have a song called `Goodbye`, but only `ABBA` has a song called `Hello`.

This way, when you want to query a particular artist, you can select the song name **and** the relevant artist name with something like:

```
SELECT s.name, a.name
FROM songs s, bridge b, artists a
WHERE b.sid = s.id AND b.aid = a.id
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I've been looking for!

Comment: Hey I managed to get the correct data for the song text, but now I have trouble echoing out the songs for the artist..  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but either all songs on the database show up, and they aren't clickable because "songid2" wont assign to them. I updated the OP could you look at it?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. `*` refers to `all rows`. It should just be **either** `SELECT * FROM...` **or** `SELECT songname, songid2 FROM...`. That **should** be your only issue, though you may want to add in a few debug commands in there to double-check nothing else is going on :) If you still have issues, it would be helpful if you could update your question to show your tables and their names. Also, OP is short for "Original Poster" -- you can't update yourself ;)

Comment: Hey, I managed to solve this after alooot of headache, apparentlt I was linking the foreign keys wrong, so I redid some table structure and everything works fine now :), thanks alot!

Comment: Awesome; glad to hear you got it all worked out in the end :)